# py2exe: loadlibrary(pythondll) error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a python (2.7) script and created an .exe of it with py2exe.
I sent the generated files to 5 friends: 3 of them could successfully start the exe, but 2 of them got this error when they try to start the exe:

```
Das angebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden:
loadlibrary(pythondll)
```

I try to translate:

```
The specified modul couldn't be found:
loadlibrary(pythondll)
```

What could be the problem there?

More information: All of my 5 friends have Windows 7 installed and no one has python installed on his/her machine. If you need more information just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If some of your friends are able to open it, I think that what you send is ok but it is possible that python.dll could not be loaded due to a missing dependency. I would recommend to ask your friend to open the exe with [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see if some files are marked as missing.

It is possible that the missing files are the Visual Studio redistribuables. I think that Python 27 requires  VS2008 runtime which can be download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29)

Comment: Thank you. But it will take a little time until my friends will have testet it ;-)